# "'this' is a reserved keyword" in React app, why?

Tags: reactjs, this, keyword, reserved

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Item from "./components/Item";
import items from "./items.json";
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {


  state = {
    items
  };

  render() {
    return (
          {this.state.items.map(item => (
          <Item
            id={item.id}
            key={item.id}
            name={item.name}
            image={item.image}

          />
      ))}
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

When I run this code I get the following error: App.js: this is a reserved word (17:11).  What can I do to fix this?

Comment: remove the `{}`, write it like this: `return (
          this.state.items.map(.....))`

Comment: Now it just says "Unexpected token, expected { (14:4)"